# How to generalize input in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am just starting to learn Haskell and I am using [learnyouahaskell.com](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) as the guide, and I am using `ghci` as interpreter. I have a question regarding lists. On the website they specify the function:

```
boomBangs xs = [ if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!" | x <- xs, odd x]
```

This works only for lists. Whereas

```
boomBangs x = [ if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!" | odd x]
```

Only works for single inputs, i.e.

```
boomBangs 21
boomBangs 7
```

Is there a way to write this statement so that it doesn't matter whether I put

```
boomBangs [2,5,6,7,1]
```

or

```
boomBangs 7
```

without the need of an if statement?

Comment: Short answer: no. Haskell needs you to define the type well for each input, but there are ways around.

Comment: there is a way (making a `Num` instance for the list - so that the literal `7` get's translated into `[7]`) - but I would not recommend it

Comment: There are various fancy typeclass tricks I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: The real question is what `boomBangs` is supposed to *mean*. When we generalize something in Haskell, we do it to express some particular *idea* more generally. What is the general `boomBang` idea? I don't really think there is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, Haskell does not allow you to just arbitrarily overload the same function name with multiple distinct implementations. There are programming languages that let you do this; Haskell is not one of them.

In general, if you want the same function to do something different for different types of arguments (or different return type, for that matter), you use type classes. However, even this does not allow you to just *arbitrarily* have different numbers or types of arguments; there must be a pattern to it.

I realise this is only for experimentation purposes, but I second the comment by dfeuer: what is `boomBangs` supposed to *mean*? What argument types does it *make sense* for? Well, obviously in this case `boomBangs` is a trivial example function, and doesn't really make much sense for anything except as an example function. (I'm not sure if you've even got to the type class part of the tutorial yet.)

Notice that, as written, `boomBangs` is *already* polymorphic: It will work for *any type* of integer. It works for signed 8-bit integers, unsigned 8-bit integers, signed 16-bit integers, unsigned 16-bit integers, arbitrary-precision integers... So it's working for quite a bit of stuff.

Making it work for lists and non-lists isn't a very natural generalisation of this function. (It is boom-bang**s**, after all.) What *might* make sense is to generalise it to work for other foldable objects (e.g., list, `Maybe`, `Either e`). It might also make sense for it to work on any monad (e.g., it looks like a slight tweak of this might work for stateful computations or parsers or I/O actions). But again, I don't know if either of those concepts have been introduced in the tutorial yet.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Name your second function differently: `boomBang`. Then write `boomBangs [2,5,6,7,1]` or `boomBang 7` -- no `if` required.

Writing code should be easy and natural, don't make it harder on yourself than it has to be.

Now you have

```
boomBangs xs = [b | x <- xs, b <- boomBang x]
```

removing the code duplication, which is usually a sign of underexplored problem space.

Comment: side note: `[b | x <- xs, b <- boomBang x]` == `concat [boomBang x | x <- xs]` == `concatMap boomBang xs` == `xs >>= boomBang`.

Answer (score 2):

You may implement different behaviors for different types using type classes. For example:

```
class BoomBang a where
    boomBang :: a -> [String]

instance BoomBang Integer where
    boomBang x = [if x < 10 then "BOOM" else "BANG" | odd x]

instance BoomBang a => BoomBang [a] where
    boomBang xs = xs >>= boomBang
```

In ghci:

```
> boomBang 7
["BOOM"]
> boomBang [2,5,6,7,1]
["BOOM","BOOM","BOOM"]
```

Comment: and `boomBang [[[2,5,6],[7,1]],[[19]]]` ==> `["BOOM","BOOM","BOOM","BANG"]`!